# Grafana count of unique values by field

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Using Grafana with the Loki source, I would like to know how to group rows by `ctx_username` and have a `ctx_username_count`

It would transform my data from

```
| ctx_username | ... |
| -------------|-----|
| username_1   | ... |
| username_1   | ... |
| username_2   | ... |
| username_1   | ... |
```

to

```
| ctx_username | ctx_username_count | ... |
| -------------|--------------------|-----|
| username_1   |         3          | ... |
| username_2   |         1          | ... |
```

in order to have a bar gauge diagram showing the number of requests made by each user (`ctx_username`) over the timerange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it working using this query

```lisp
sum by (ctx_username) (
    count_over_time(
        {service_type="my-app"} | json | ctx_username !="" | __error__="" [$__interval]
    )
)
```

Calculation: Total, Numeric Fields
Transform: Join by labels `ctx_username`

When using bargauge, I also had to reduce Query Options > Max data points to 1 in order to have the right scale, it also made my query much faster.